# on Joomla 3.1 where do I go in the code to hide the following buttons showned below wysigwig editor

Tags: editor, joomla3.0

On Joomla 3  wysiwig editor  I would like to hide the buttons used to insert images and articles. The buttons show below the wysiwig editor (I use Joomla CKE) .

How Can I hide them so they are not displayed or used?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [JCE Editor](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/languages). It allows the best integration and allows you to choose every option that is available. It is the best way to prevent clients getting a little over keen with what they can change

On a side note: Joomla 3.1 is out of date now and has security issues. Please upgrade to 3.2.x asap

Answer (score 0):

Disable the corresponding editor-xtd plugins in the plugin manager.
That's not a code question however.